# Jmeter results are not published to Dashboard

Tags: jmeter, influxdb

We are trying to have real time results showing on Grafana. `Jmeter` Master is launched in `GCP (Google cloud platform)` and we have one Windows VM in GCP which has `Grafana` and `InfluxDB` has been installed and configured.

When executed `Jmeter` in Windows VM, able to publish data in `Grafana` and `InfluxDB` web UI. However when tried the same from GCP Master instance getting 'connection timeout to influxDB server'. Followed below steps:

1. Windows VM where `InfluxDB` and `Grafana` configued. (x.x.x.1: IP is the GCP local ip, not public ip)
   Grafana can be accessed: http://x.x.x.1:3000

InfluxDB: http://x.x.x.1:8086

2. The `Jmeter` Test Plan contains `'BackendListner'` added as below.
   Run the `Jmeter` 5.2 in Windows VM, results are published to both `InfluxDB` and `Grafana` web UI.
3. Now copied the Test Plan to GCP Jmeter Master instance (x.x.x.2 - local IP) and execute 
   ./jmeter -n -t Testplan.jmx

[image]

4. In `Jmeter` logs, it shows:

[image]

Tried by passing public IP in the BackendListner for influxDB host, that also didn't work. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the machines are in the same [VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/) - use internal IP addresses
2. If the machines are not in the same VPC - use external IP addresses
3. In both case you need to amend [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) on the InfluxDB machine to allow inbound connections on port `8086`

References:

- [GCE - Networking - IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/)
- [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results - Part 2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dmitri, after setting InboundRule to allow port 8086 in Windows VM able to get results published on Grafana.